# ConstrainedTypeUnified error from Prim.Union

Tags: purescript

I want to define a `Record` type `Rec3` as the union of two rows so that I can use `Rec3` as the argument for function `func1`.

```hs
import Prim.Row (class Union)

type Row1 = (x1 :: Int)
type Row2 = (x2 :: String)
type Rec3 = forall r. Union Row1 Row2 r => Record r

func1 :: Rec3 -> String
func1 {x1,x2} = show x1 <> x2
```

that seems to compile okay, but when I add a call to `func1`,

```hs
func1 {x1:3,x2:"t"}
```

```
Could not match type

    r0

  with type

    ( x1 :: Int
    | t1
    )


while trying to match type r0
  with type ( x1 :: Int
            | t1
            )
while checking that expression { x1: 3
                               , x2: "t"
                               }
  has type Record r0
in value declaration main

where r0 is a rigid type variable
        bound at (line 22, column 47 - line 22, column 60)
      t1 is an unknown type

See https://github.com/purescript/documentation/blob/master/errors/ConstrainedTypeUnified.md for more information,
or to contribute content related to this error.
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `forall` is in the wrong place.

You probably meant the signature of `func1` to be this:

```
func1 :: forall r. Union Row1 Row2 r => Record r -> String
```

But the way you declared it, it's actually this:

```
func1 :: (forall r. Union Row1 Row2 r => Record r) -> String
```

Note the parens. They're important.

In the first signature, `forall r` applies to the whole function, which means that whoever calls the function chooses what `r` is. In the second signature, however, `forall r` applies just to the first parameter, which means that whoever tries to access that parameter chooses what `r` is. And this means that whoever calls `func1` doesn't choose `r`, but on the contrary, must somehow pass in a record of a generic type. Which is, of course, impossible.

---

If you want to combine two records, you can define `Rec1` and `Rec2` as extensible rows (i.e. with a parameter) and then you can combine them by passing one row as a parameter to the other:

```
type Row1 r = (x1 :: Int | r)
type Row2 = (x2 :: String)
type Rec3 = Record (Row1 Row2)
```

For more on this, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51987983/180286) I wrote a while ago.